# jquery not work after async post back ocuur

Tags: jquery, asp.net, asynchronous, updatepanel

I use below code for toggling my main navigation :

```
    $(document).ready(function () {
    var body, click_event, content, nav, nav_toggler;
    nav_toggler = $("header .toggle-nav");
    nav = $("#main-nav");
    content = $("#content");
    body = $("body");
    click_event = (jQuery.support.touch ? "tap" : "click");
    $("#main-nav .dropdown-collapse").on(click_event, function (e) {
        var link, list;
        e.preventDefault();
        link = $(this);
        list = link.parent().find("> ul");
        if (list.is(":visible")) {
            if (body.hasClass("main-nav-closed") && link.parents("li").length === 1) {
                false;
            } else {
                link.removeClass("in");
                list.slideUp(300, function () {
                    return $(this).removeClass("in");
                });
            }
        } else {
            if (list.parents("ul.nav.nav-stacked").length === 1) {
                $(document).trigger("nav-open");
            }
            link.addClass("in");
            list.slideDown(300, function () {
                return $(this).addClass("in");
            });
        }
        return false;
    });

    if (jQuery.support.touch) {
        nav.on("swiperight", function (e) {
            return $(document).trigger("nav-open");
        });
        nav.on("swipeleft", function (e) {
            return $(document).trigger("nav-close");
        });
    }
    nav_toggler.on(click_event, function () {
        if (nav_open()) {
            $(document).trigger("nav-close");
        } else {
            $(document).trigger("nav-open");
        }
        return false;
    });

    $(document).bind("nav-close", function (event, params) {
        var nav_open;
        body.removeClass("main-nav-opened").addClass("main-nav-closed");
        return nav_open = false;
    });
    return $(document).bind("nav-open", function (event, params) {
        var nav_open;
        body.addClass("main-nav-opened").removeClass("main-nav-closed");
        return nav_open = true;
    });
});

this.nav_open = function () {
    return $("body").hasClass("main-nav-opened") || $("#main-nav").width() > 50;
};
```

but this code not worked after async post back occur in asp.net. please help me to know why this happen, and how I chnage this code to toggle menu after post back.

this is my menu before toggle : 
[image]

and this is my menu after toggling : 
[image]

and this is my asp.net codes:

```
<nav id='main-nav'>
<asp:UpdatePanel runat="server" ID="upExpander">
    <ContentTemplate>
        <asp:HiddenField ID="hfMenu" runat="server" Value="1" />
        <div class='navigation'>
            <ul class='nav nav-stacked'>
                <li>
                    <a href="#" class="dropdown-collapse">
                        <i class="icon-gears"></i>
                        <span><%=Resources.Titles.ProjectList %></span>
                        <i class="icon-angle-down angle-down"></i>
                    </a>
                    <ul class='nav nav-stacked'>
                        <asp:HiddenField runat="server" ID="hfFolderID" />
                        <asp:ListView ID="lvProjects" runat="server" DataSourceID="odsProject" DataKeyNames="ID" OnItemDataBound="lvProjects_ItemDataBound">
                            <ItemTemplate>

                                <li>
                                    <asp:LinkButton ID="lbtnProject" runat="server" OnClick="lbtnProject_Click" data-expand="collapse">
                                        <i class='icon-gears'></i>
                                        <span><%#System.Convert.ToString(Eval("Name").ToString().Length<30 ? Eval("Name") : Eval("Name").ToString().Substring(0,30) + "..." ) %></span>
                                    </asp:LinkButton>
                                    <ul class='nav nav-stacked'>
                                        <asp:ListView ID="lvFolder" runat="server" DataKeyNames="ID" OnItemDataBound="lvFolder_ItemDataBound">
                                            <ItemTemplate>
                                                <li>
                                                    <asp:LinkButton ID="lbtnFolder" runat="server" OnClick="lbtnFolder_Click">
                                                        <i class='icon-folder'></i>
                                                        <span><%#System.Convert.ToString(Eval("Name").ToString().Length<30 ? Eval("Name") : Eval("Name").ToString().Substring(0,30) + "..." ) %></span>
                                                    </asp:LinkButton>
                                                    <asp:LinkButton ID="lbtnAddDocument" runat="server" CssClass="addDocument" OnClientClick="ShowModalBox('modal_AddDocument');" OnClick="lbtnAddDocument_Click">
                                                        <i class="icon icomoon-icon-AddDocument hasTooltip" title="<%=Resources.Titles.AddDocument %>"></i>
                                                    </asp:LinkButton>
                                                </li>
                                            </ItemTemplate>
                                        </asp:ListView>
                                    </ul>
                                    <asp:LinkButton ID="lbtnAddFolder" runat="server" CssClass="addFolder" OnClientClick="ShowModalBox('AddFolderModal');" OnClick="lbtnAddFolder_Click">
                                <i class="icon icomoon-icon-AddFolder hasTooltip" title="<%=Resources.Titles.AddFolder %>"></i>
                                    </asp:LinkButton>
                                </li>
                            </ItemTemplate>
                        </asp:ListView>
                        <asp:ObjectDataSource ID="odsProject" runat="server" TypeName="DMS.Data.ProjectProvider" SelectMethod="GetUserProjects" OnSelecting="odsProject_Selecting">
                            <SelectParameters>
                                <asp:Parameter Name="userID" Type="Int32" />
                            </SelectParameters>
                        </asp:ObjectDataSource>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <%--<li>
                    <a href="#" class="dropdown-collapse">
                        <i class="icon-gears"></i>
                        <span><%=Resources.Titles.MyFolders %></span>
                        <i class="icon-angle-down angle-down"></i>
                    </a>
                    <ul class='nav nav-stacked'>
                        <asp:HiddenField runat="server" ID="hfMyFolderID" />
                        <asp:ListView ID="lvMyFolders" runat="server" DataSourceID="odsMyFolders" DataKeyNames="ID" OnItemDataBound="">
                            <ItemTemplate>
                                <li>
                                    <asp:LinkButton ID="lbtnMyFolder" runat="server" OnClick="">
                                        <i class='icon-gears'></i>
                                        <span><%#System.Convert.ToString(Eval("Name").ToString().Length<30 ? Eval("Name") : Eval("Name").ToString().Substring(0,30) + "..." ) %></span>
                                    </asp:LinkButton>
                                    <ul class='nav nav-stacked'>
                                        <asp:Literal runat="server" ID="litSubfolders"/>
                                    </ul>
                                    <asp:LinkButton ID="lbtnAddFolder" runat="server" CssClass="addFolder" OnClientClick="ShowModalBox('AddFolderModal');" OnClick="lbtnAddFolder_Click">
                                <i class="icon icomoon-icon-AddFolder hasTooltip" title="<%=Resources.Titles.AddFolder %>"></i>
                                    </asp:LinkButton>
                                </li>
                            </ItemTemplate>
                        </asp:ListView>
                        <asp:ObjectDataSource ID="odsMyFolders" runat="server" TypeName="DMS.Data.VirtualFolderProvider" SelectMethod="GetUserFolders" OnSelecting="">
                            <SelectParameters>
                                <asp:Parameter Name="userID" Type="Int32" />
                            </SelectParameters>
                        </asp:ObjectDataSource>
                    </ul>
                </li>--%>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

and this is generated html code :

```
<nav id="main-nav">
<div id="ucExpander_upExpander">

        <input type="hidden" name="ctl00$ucExpander$hfMenu" id="ucExpander_hfMenu" value="ucExpander_lvProjects_lbtnProject_0">
        <div class="navigation">
            <ul class="nav nav-stacked">
                <li>
                    <a href="#" class="dropdown-collapse in">
                        <i class="icon-gears"></i>
                        <span>لیست پروژه ها</span>
                        <i class="icon-angle-down angle-down"></i>
                    </a>
                    <ul class="nav nav-stacked in" style="display: block;">
                        <input type="hidden" name="ctl00$ucExpander$hfFolderID" id="ucExpander_hfFolderID">


                                <li>
                                    <a onclick="updateExpandData(this, 'ucExpander_hfMenu');" id="ucExpander_lvProjects_lbtnProject_0" class="dropdown-collapse" data-expand="collapse" href="javascript:__doPostBack('ctl00$ucExpander$lvProjects$ctrl0$lbtnProject','')">
                                        <i class="icon-gears"></i>
                                        <span>سامانه مدیریت اسناد</span>
                                    <i class="icon-angle-down angle-down"></i></a>
                                    <ul class="nav nav-stacked" style="display: none;">

                                                <li>
                                                    <a id="ucExpander_lvProjects_lvFolder_0_lbtnFolder_0" href="javascript:__doPostBack('ctl00$ucExpander$lvProjects$ctrl0$lvFolder$ctrl0$lbtnFolder','')">
                                                        <i class="icon-folder"></i>
                                                        <span>aa</span>
                                                    </a>
                                                    <a onclick="ShowModalBox('modal_AddDocument');" id="ucExpander_lvProjects_lvFolder_0_lbtnAddDocument_0" class="addDocument" href="javascript:__doPostBack('ctl00$ucExpander$lvProjects$ctrl0$lvFolder$ctrl0$lbtnAddDocument','')">
                                                        <i class="icon icomoon-icon-AddDocument hasTooltip" title="" data-original-title="درج سند جدید"></i>
                                                    </a>
                                                </li>

                                                <li>
                                                    <a id="ucExpander_lvProjects_lvFolder_0_lbtnFolder_1" href="javascript:__doPostBack('ctl00$ucExpander$lvProjects$ctrl0$lvFolder$ctrl1$lbtnFolder','')">
                                                        <i class="icon-folder"></i>
                                                        <span>bb</span>
                                                    </a>
                                                    <a onclick="ShowModalBox('modal_AddDocument');" id="ucExpander_lvProjects_lvFolder_0_lbtnAddDocument_1" class="addDocument" href="javascript:__doPostBack('ctl00$ucExpander$lvProjects$ctrl0$lvFolder$ctrl1$lbtnAddDocument','')">
                                                        <i class="icon icomoon-icon-AddDocument hasTooltip" title="" data-original-title="درج سند جدید"></i>
                                                    </a>
                                                </li>

                                                <li>
                                                    <a id="ucExpander_lvProjects_lvFolder_0_lbtnFolder_2" href="javascript:__doPostBack('ctl00$ucExpander$lvProjects$ctrl0$lvFolder$ctrl2$lbtnFolder','')">
                                                        <i class="icon-folder"></i>
                                                        <span>cc</span>
                                                    </a>
                                                    <a onclick="ShowModalBox('modal_AddDocument');" id="ucExpander_lvProjects_lvFolder_0_lbtnAddDocument_2" class="addDocument" href="javascript:__doPostBack('ctl00$ucExpander$lvProjects$ctrl0$lvFolder$ctrl2$lbtnAddDocument','')">
                                                        <i class="icon icomoon-icon-AddDocument hasTooltip" title="" data-original-title="درج سند جدید"></i>
                                                    </a>
                                                </li>

                                                <li>
                                                    <a id="ucExpander_lvProjects_lvFolder_0_lbtnFolder_3" href="javascript:__doPostBack('ctl00$ucExpander$lvProjects$ctrl0$lvFolder$ctrl3$lbtnFolder','')">
                                                        <i class="icon-folder"></i>
                                                        <span>dd</span>
                                                    </a>
                                                    <a onclick="ShowModalBox('modal_AddDocument');" id="ucExpander_lvProjects_lvFolder_0_lbtnAddDocument_3" class="addDocument" href="javascript:__doPostBack('ctl00$ucExpander$lvProjects$ctrl0$lvFolder$ctrl3$lbtnAddDocument','')">
                                                        <i class="icon icomoon-icon-AddDocument hasTooltip" title="" data-original-title="درج سند جدید"></i>
                                                    </a>
                                                </li>

                                                <li>
                                                    <a id="ucExpander_lvProjects_lvFolder_0_lbtnFolder_4" href="javascript:__doPostBack('ctl00$ucExpander$lvProjects$ctrl0$lvFolder$ctrl4$lbtnFolder','')">
                                                        <i class="icon-folder"></i>
                                                        <span>ee</span>
                                                    </a>
                                                    <a onclick="ShowModalBox('modal_AddDocument');" id="ucExpander_lvProjects_lvFolder_0_lbtnAddDocument_4" class="addDocument" href="javascript:__doPostBack('ctl00$ucExpander$lvProjects$ctrl0$lvFolder$ctrl4$lbtnAddDocument','')">
                                                        <i class="icon icomoon-icon-AddDocument hasTooltip" title="" data-original-title="درج سند جدید"></i>
                                                    </a>
                                                </li>

                                    </ul>
                                    <a onclick="ShowModalBox('AddFolderModal');" id="ucExpander_lvProjects_lbtnAddFolder_0" class="addFolder" href="javascript:__doPostBack('ctl00$ucExpander$lvProjects$ctrl0$lbtnAddFolder','')">
                                <i class="icon icomoon-icon-AddFolder hasTooltip" title="" data-original-title="ایجاد فولدر"></i>
                                    </a>
                                </li>


                                <li>
                                    <a onclick="updateExpandData(this, 'ucExpander_hfMenu');" id="ucExpander_lvProjects_lbtnProject_1" class="dropdown-collapse" data-expand="collapse" href="javascript:__doPostBack('ctl00$ucExpander$lvProjects$ctrl1$lbtnProject','')">
                                        <i class="icon-gears"></i>
                                        <span>سامانه مدیریت و درج روزانه کار...</span>
                                    <i class="icon-angle-down angle-down"></i></a>
                                    <ul class="nav nav-stacked">

                                                <li>
                                                    <a id="ucExpander_lvProjects_lvFolder_1_lbtnFolder_0" href="javascript:__doPostBack('ctl00$ucExpander$lvProjects$ctrl1$lvFolder$ctrl0$lbtnFolder','')">
                                                        <i class="icon-folder"></i>
                                                        <span>bbb</span>
                                                    </a>
                                                    <a onclick="ShowModalBox('modal_AddDocument');" id="ucExpander_lvProjects_lvFolder_1_lbtnAddDocument_0" class="addDocument" href="javascript:__doPostBack('ctl00$ucExpander$lvProjects$ctrl1$lvFolder$ctrl0$lbtnAddDocument','')">
                                                        <i class="icon icomoon-icon-AddDocument hasTooltip" title="" data-original-title="درج سند جدید"></i>
                                                    </a>
                                                </li>

                                                <li>
                                                    <a id="ucExpander_lvProjects_lvFolder_1_lbtnFolder_1" href="javascript:__doPostBack('ctl00$ucExpander$lvProjects$ctrl1$lvFolder$ctrl1$lbtnFolder','')">
                                                        <i class="icon-folder"></i>
                                                        <span>ff</span>
                                                    </a>
                                                    <a onclick="ShowModalBox('modal_AddDocument');" id="ucExpander_lvProjects_lvFolder_1_lbtnAddDocument_1" class="addDocument" href="javascript:__doPostBack('ctl00$ucExpander$lvProjects$ctrl1$lvFolder$ctrl1$lbtnAddDocument','')">
                                                        <i class="icon icomoon-icon-AddDocument hasTooltip" title="" data-original-title="درج سند جدید"></i>
                                                    </a>
                                                </li>

                                    </ul>

                                </li>


                                <li>
                                    <a onclick="updateExpandData(this, 'ucExpander_hfMenu');" id="ucExpander_lvProjects_lbtnProject_2" data-expand="collapse" href="javascript:__doPostBack('ctl00$ucExpander$lvProjects$ctrl2$lbtnProject','')">
                                        <i class="icon-gears"></i>
                                        <span>سامانه مدیریت هوشمند ماموریت</span>
                                    </a>
                                    <ul class="nav nav-stacked">

                                    </ul>

                                </li>


                                <li>
                                    <a onclick="updateExpandData(this, 'ucExpander_hfMenu');" id="ucExpander_lvProjects_lbtnProject_3" data-expand="collapse" href="javascript:__doPostBack('ctl00$ucExpander$lvProjects$ctrl3$lbtnProject','')">
                                        <i class="icon-gears"></i>
                                        <span>سامانه مهر بندرعباس</span>
                                    </a>
                                    <ul class="nav nav-stacked">

                                    </ul>

                                </li>


                    </ul>
                </li>

            </ul>
        </div>
```

please help me to solve this problem. thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't tell what the asynchronous postback does, but as there are not ASP.NET controls in the code that you show, I assume that it's all inside a control.

That means that the code is replaced by a new version of the same by the asynchronous call, so any events that you bound to the elements are gone as those elements doesn't exist any more.

You can use delegated events to bind the event outside the elements that are replaced by the asynchronous call. This will bind it to the `body` element, but you should use an element closer to the target elements if possible:

```
$("body").on(click_event, "#main-nav .dropdown-collapse", function (e) {
```

Comment: sorry I give my generated html, I have a asp.net linkButton control as my .dropdown-collapse Item. an async postback is a partial post back and occur when a button inside an update panel occur.

Comment: @minamorsali: Yes, the partial postback means that all the code inside any update panel that is marked for update will be replaced.

Comment: Thank you Guffa , This code resolve my problem. but another thing that I need is that my .dropdown-collapse item that is a link button can post backs and run onclick event after toggle , but now this can't do, I comment out returns but post back not occur , can you help me for this?

Comment: @minamorsali: If you mean that the postback should only happen when the menu is expanded, then you should only use `preventDefault` in that case. When using `preventDefault` you don't need to return `false`.

Comment: No , I need post back occur when I click on .dropdown-collapse , but e.preventdefault and return false prevent from this. how can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

you can use this script

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        // if you use jQuery, you can load them when dom is read.
        $(document).ready(function () {
            var prm = Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance();
            prm.add_initializeRequest(InitializeRequest);
            prm.add_endRequest(EndRequest);

            // Place here the first init of the DatePicker
            jValid();
        });

        function InitializeRequest(sender, args) {
            // make unbind to avoid memory leaks.
            jValid();
        }

        function EndRequest(sender, args) {
            // after update occur on UpdatePanel re-init the DatePicker
            jValid();
        }
        function jValid()
        {
             //your code here
            }
            });


        }
    </script>
```